# Foreach() on Array

Tags: php

I understand that this foreach() statement is printing out the field 'name_first' from every item in the array that was fed to it...

```
foreach ($data as $author) { 
    print get('name_first', $author) . 
    " " . get('emailaddress', $author) .
    "<br/>";
    if(strpos($author['emailaddress'], ">")) { 
        $sp->update($listName, $author['id'], array('emailaddress'=> email_from_link($author['emailaddress'])));
    }
```

But can someone just explain what the last if statement is doing? It really doesn't make any sense to me.

```
if(strpos($author['emailaddress'], ">")) { 
    $sp->update($listName, $author['id'], array('emailaddress'=> email_from_link($author['emailaddress'])));
```

Comment: It checks if the email address contains `>` from the second character on anywhere in the string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's checking for the character `>` in the string `$author['emailaddress']` after the first character.

If `>` exists, then `update` the array `$sp` with the values specified between the parentheses.

Comment: To be exact it only checks it from the second character on

Answer (score 4):

It's asking of the position of the `>` character in the string.  If the character is at any position other than the first character, the if-block will be entered.

This is what I'd consider sloppy/lazy programming - it's a bad idea to get in the habit of treating ints and booleans the same way, especially when a function like `strpos` can return an integer 0 and also false:

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> Warning This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
> non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE.

Furthermore code like that ends up confusing people, as has happened in your case. Far better to code explicitly:

```
$index = strpos($author['emailaddress'], '>');

if(FALSE === $index) {
    // Handle error
} 
else if($index > 0) {
    $sp->update($listName, $author['id'], array('emailaddress'=> email_from_link($author['emailaddress'])));
}
```

It's more verbose, certainly, but as a result it's easier to understand and therefore easier to *maintain*.